Movie about an airplane forced to keep climbing because of an in-air incident
I remember seeing about half of an older movie about an airplane that had an in-air incident (I think it was a collision with a smaller aircraft that wasn't supposed to be there) that caused certain flaps to become stuck, forcing the plane to keep climbing until the air would become too thin.
I am not sure what time the movie was released, but judging from what I remembered from the picture quality, I think it was around the 80s-90s.
Aspects I believe I remember from the movie:

I saw the movie in the late 90s, on Flemish TV (most likely VRT, but could also have been VTM) in the evening. the movie was English with Dutch subtitles;
The smaller plane was a top-winged plane with fixed landing gear, and I think the pilot was portrayed as a stereotypical obnoxious American;
An army chopper was sent to escort the plane, and a veteran on-board the plane was explained the situation and asked how big a hole the chopper could shoot in the flaps. The answer was "about the size of your fists";
Some of the people onboard the plane were asked to go to the back of the plane to rip out the interior paneling so they could inspect the damage.

I was young back then, and it was my bedtime before the movie ended. I only just remembered the movie and am curious which one it was.

It's not this one, is it?

@Walt It's not that one. In fact, it's none of the ones mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_aviation_accidents_and_incidents as far as I can tell.

OK, thanks. Posted a better match.

Sounds like the plot of Final Descent from 1997 with Robert Urich and Annette O'Toole.

A passenger airplane is involved in a mid-air collision [with a light plane] shortly after takeoff. The damage forces it to continue to climb higher and higher, which computer simulations indicate will rip the plane in two. While trying to get the plane safely back on the ground, the captain on the flight must deal with the airline inspector (who holds a grudge from a previous encounters), his feelings for the co-pilot (his girlfriend), and the manufacturer of the plane (whose recommendations for action are not ethically motivated).

At some point a helicopter flying alongside it shoots at the flaps or elevators. Here's the trailer:




Yes, that seems really like the movie that I watched. The timeframe matches, the pilot of the smaller plane is about what I remember and I doubt there would have been 2 movies with this plot in that period. I'll accept it for now, since I can still change that if necessary.
